# Connect an Apple 24" LED Cinema Display to a PC

Tags: display, lcd

Is it possible to connect an Apple 24" LED Cinema Display to a PC?

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, It only has a Display port connector on it, so you will need an adapter... unless you have one of the rare computers that has it.

[Just found this](http://www.atlona.com/Atlona-DVI-to-Mini-DisplayPort-Converter-p-17859.html)

[image]

Comment: @Wil I think you edited the wrong answer :)

Comment: @Wil I added the link and picture to your answer since you found the information. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @Alex didn't see anyone else had an answer... well, +1 to you and your answer! sorry - feel free to put that pic in your answer and get the point here!

Comment: No, no, you found the information :). I'll give you +1 for being a good sport and for having the better answer.

Comment: Geffen also makes one ( http://www.gefen.com/kvm/dproduct.jsp?prod_id=8913 ) — it's a bit cheaper, and they're a pretty darn reputable brand.

Comment: @SidneySM, +1Thanks, I do not really recommend that brand - I posted picture and link as an example only... but good information to the original poster if you recommend a cheaper product.

Answer (score 1):

I know when it came out it was impossible to connect it to anything other than MacBooks that had mini DisplayPorts. I don't think there are a lot of PCs with mini DisplayPorts out there; it might be kind of hard.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the DVI to MDP converter box, it ought to be possible to use a simple cable to convert normal DP to the MBP used by the LED Cinema Display. I'm unaware of a cable to do so at present, though.

ATi's new Eyefinity cards will come with MDP sockets, although I expect them to cost a lot since they are "enthusiast" level card, great for games and being able to drive 6 seperate displays.