# Can I connect an Apple display to my PC?

Tags: graphics-card, display

Soon I will change my monitor. Apple monitors seem so powerful for print design. 
My graphic card has RGB, DVI Outputs. Am I able to connect Apple Displays to my PC?

Thunderbolt Display or any other Apple Display?

I saw this question: [Connect an Apple 24" LED Cinema Display to a PC](https://superuser.com/questions/50423/connect-an-apple-24-led-cinema-display-to-a-pc)

… but it seems that the answer's not accepted, and it's two years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has two display types:

- [Thunderbolt connected](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC914LL/A?fnode=MTY1NDA5OQ)
- [Mini DisplayPort connected](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC007LL/A?fnode=MTY1NDA5OQ)

I guess Thunderbolt is not what you want. So your options to connect are:

- Get a graphics card with a dedicated Mini DisplayPort output
- Get a converter from DVI → MDP. That *should* work, **but** you need to make sure your graphics card can actually handle the resolution.

Note that you won't be able to use the built-in iSight camera. Also, it seems that compatibility here is not easy to test, and I'd go look for some specific graphics card or converter models in various forums, or even on the Apple discussions: ["This looks great! Does this work with PCs?"](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MC007LL/A?fnode=MTY1NDA5OQ&pqid=QTPPYAYY9KY9P4PKUKADUKXC2KH7JPYKT)